# Ternary (conditional) expression has the wrong type

Tags: c, gcc, conditional-operator

I found these two implementation are NOT equal:

```
1.num = sign ? (int)va_arg(args, int) : (unsigned int)va_arg(args, unsigned int);

2.if (sign)
    num = (int)va_arg(args, int);
else    
    num = (unsigned int)va_arg(args, unsigned int);
```

the 1st implementation, it always chooses the false branch, no matter what value the *sign* is.

the 2nd one works as expected.

what happends here? I'm using GCC/ARM GCC 64bit

Comment: The first one doesn't "always choose the false branch", but the result of the conditional is always `unsigned int`, i.e. when the `true` branch is chosen, the value will be `(unsigned int)(int)va_arg(args, int)`, which is most likely equal to what you would get from the false branch

Comment: @Leslie Li  I think you are mistaken. The problem is that the common type for signed int and unsigned int is unsigned int.

Comment: To improve the question, show how you are determining that the false branch was chosen

Comment: And also give the type of num.  That is important.

Comment: typeof num is unsigned long long. if I changed 1st one to:
num = sign ? (int)va_arg(args, int) : 1234;
and passed in int arg -1, I will get -1 by (signed long long)num.
The original implementation, I will get 0xffffffff if passed in -1. It should be 0xffffffffffffffff if goes to true branch.

Comment: @M.M why it forced convert (int)va_arg(args, int) expression to (unsigned int)? it is an implict rule of exp ? exp : exp; ??

Comment: Yes, every expression has its type known at compile time (other than the array size of variably modified arrays) ; the result of a conditional is no exception

Comment: To fix the problem you could cast the va_arg to `unsigned long long` instead of the existing casts (which are redundant since va_arg is defined to evaluate to a value of the requested type)

Comment: @M.M I think I understand, the num is forced to use (unsigned int) at compile time. thanks a lot, it explaines the issue!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would guess that the problem you are running into is the subtle, implicit promotion that takes place in the `?:` operator. The 2nd and 3rd operands are balanced against each other through *the usual arithmetic conversions*. This is mandated by C11 6.5.15:

> If both the second and third operands have arithmetic type, the result
>   type that would be determined by the usual arithmetic conversions,
>   were they applied to those two operands, is the type of the result.

Meaning if one is signed and the other is unsigned, the signed operand gets converted to unsigned. This happens regardless of which one of the 2nd or 3rd operands that gets evaluated and used as result.

This can cause curious bugs if you aren't aware of this oddity:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  int x;
  if( (-1 ? (printf("Expression evaluates to -1\n"),-1) : 0xFFFFFFFF) < 0)
  {
    printf("-1 is < 0");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("-1 is >= 0");
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Expression evaluates to -1
-1 is >= 0
```

This is the reason why `if/else` is to be preferred over `?:`.